# Why is there て form at the end of the sentence? 先生もいっしょにいらっしゃらないかなと思いまして

Tags: grammar, て-form

> 明日みんなで桜を見に行くんですが、先生もいっしょにいらっしゃらないかなと**思いまして**。

Why is it there? And does it make any difference in meaning compared to dictionary form for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> て ㊁〘終助〙
>   ❷ 《「…でして」「…まして」「…してしまって」の形で》原因や理由、状況を示して釈明を表す。「お子様限定のサービスでし**て**。」「電車が遅れまし**て**。」「遅くなりまし**て**。」「つい忘れちゃっ**て**。」

The て in your example is used to express a cause, reason or explanation/vindication.

> 明日みんなで桜を見に行くんですが、先生もいっしょにいらっしゃらないかなと思いまし**て**。

"Tomorrow we're going to see cherry blossoms and I'm (we're) wondering if you'd like to join us (*and that's why I came to you / that's why I'm calling you / that's why I just asked if you'd be free tomorrow, etc.*)"

→ indirectly/politely inviting "Would you like to join us?" (as pointed out in the comment)

---

「～～先生もいっしょにいらっしゃらないかなと思いまし**た**。」 would just be a statement to say that you wondered/thought of that.

Comment: I was wondering about this.  Given the lack of context... and given the politeness level, couldn't this be a rather indirect way of asking the teacher is they would like to come along (assuming it's being spoken to the teacher).  And if not spoken to the teacher, it sounds a bit like an overly polite soliloquy to oneself.  Anyhow, I'd be interested to hear what your thoughts are on these possible interpretations.

Comment: @A.Ellett Oh yes, it's practically saying "Would you like to join us?" 「明日みんなで桜を見に行くんですが、先生もいっしょにいらっしゃいませんか？」 in an indirect and polite way. It's not a soliloquy to oneself. Thank you for the comment.